# Assigning block pointers: differences between Objective-C vs C++ classes

Tags: pointers, clang, subclass, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

I’ve found that assigning blocks behaves differently with respect to Objective-C class parameters and C++ classes parameters.

Imagine I have this simple Objective-C class hierarchy:

```
@interface Fruit : NSObject
@end

@interface Apple : Fruit
@end
```

Then I can write stuff like this:

```
Fruit *(^getFruit)();
Apple *(^getApple)();
getFruit = getApple;
```

This means that, *with respect to Objective-C classes*, blocks are **covariant in their return type**: a block which returns something more specific can be seen as a “subclass” of a block returning something more general. Here, the `getApple` block, which delivers an apple, can be safely assigned to the `getFruit` block. Indeed, if used later, it's always save to receive an `Apple *` when you're expecting a `Fruit *`. And, logically, the converse does not work: `getApple = getFruit;` doesn't compile, because when we really want an apple, we're not happy getting just a fruit.

Similarly, I can write this:

```
void (^eatFruit)(Fruit *);
void (^eatApple)(Apple *);
eatApple = eatFruit;
```

This shows that blocks are **covariant in their argument types**: a block that can process an argument that is more general can be used where a block that processes an argument that is more specific is needed. If a block knows how to eat a fruit, it will know how to eat an apple as well. Again, the converse is not true, and this will not compile: `eatFruit = eatApple;`.

This is all good and well — in Objective-C. Now let's try that in C++ or Objective-C++, supposing we have these similar C++ classes:

```
class FruitCpp {};

class AppleCpp : public FruitCpp {};

class OrangeCpp : public FruitCpp {};
```

Sadly, these block assignments don't compile any more:

```
 FruitCpp *(^getFruitCpp)();
 AppleCpp *(^getAppleCpp)();
 getFruitCpp = getAppleCpp; // error!

 void (^eatFruitCpp)(FruitCpp *);
 void (^eatAppleCpp)(AppleCpp *);
 eatAppleCpp = eatFruitCpp; // error!
```

Clang complains with an “assigning from incompatible type” error. So, *with respect to C++ classes*, blocks appear to be **invariant in the return type and parameter types**.

Why is that? Doesn't the same argument I made with Objective-C classes also hold for C++ classes? What am I missing?

Comment: Most likely, the feature was simply overlooked. There are [commits](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=125445) that show Clang people caring about making covariance and contravariance work in Objective-C++ for Objective-C types but I couldn't find anything for C++ itself. The [language specification for blocks](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html) doesn't mention either.

Comment: Should I file this somewhere (where?) as a bug/feature request?

Comment: You can file bugs and feature requests for LLVM projects [here](http://llvm.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi) (requires free registration with valid e-mail, like most public bugtrackers do), but expect a delay of at least a couple of months. If you're really into it, the people on the mailing list might be happy to assist you if you want to make the patch yourself.

Comment: I reported a bug with ARC last September and it was acknowledged at the beginning of February with an Apple engineer stating that it was being "tracked internally at rdar://..." (so they started working on it, I guess).

Comment: I've open a bug: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15484. If you turn your comment(s) into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This distinction is intentional, due to the differences between the Objective-C and C++ object models. In particular, given a pointer to an Objective-C object, one can convert/cast that pointer to point at a base class or a derived class without actually changing the value of the pointer: the address of the object is the same regardless.

Because C++ allows multiple and virtual inheritance, this is not the case for C++ objects: if I have a pointer to a C++ class and I cast/convert that pointer to point at a base class or a derived class, I may have to adjust the value of the pointer. For example, consider:

```
class A { int x; }
class B { int y; }
class C : public A, public B { }

B *getC() { 
  C *c = new C;
  return c;
}
```

Let's say that the new C object in getC() gets allocated at address 0x10. The value of the pointer 'c' is 0x10. In the return statement, that pointer to C needs to be adjusted to point at the B subobject within C. Because B comes after A in C's inheritance list, it will (generally) be laid out in memory after A, so this means adding an offset of 4 bytes (
== sizeof(A)) to the pointer, so the returned pointer will be 0x14. Similarly, casting a B* to a C* would subtract 4 bytes from the pointer, to account for B's offset within C. When dealing with virtual base classes, the idea is the same but the offsets are no longer known, compile-time constants: they're accessed through the vtable during execution.

Now, consider the effect this has on an assignment like:

```
C (^getC)();
B (^getB)();
getB = getC;
```

The getC block returns a pointer to a C. To turn it into a block that returns a pointer to a B, we would need to adjust the pointer returned from each invocation of the block by adding 4 bytes. This isn't an adjustment to the block; it's an adjustment to the pointer value returned by the block. One could implement this by synthesizing a new block that wraps the previous block and performs the adjustment, e.g.,

```
getB = ^B() { return getC() }
```

This is implementable in the compiler, which already introduces similar "thunks" when overriding a virtual function with one that has a covariant return type needing adjustment. However, with blocks it causes an additional problem: blocks allow equality comparison with ==, so to evaluate whether "getB == getC", we would have to be able to look through the thunk that would be generated by the assignment "getB = getC" to compare the underlying block pointers. Again, this is implementable, but would require a much more heavyweight blocks runtime that is able to create (uniqued) thunks able to perform these adjustments to the return value (and as well as for any contravariant parameters). While all of this is technically possible, the cost (in runtime size, complexity, and execution time) outweighs the benefits.

Getting back to Objective-C, the single-inheritance object model never needs any adjustments to the object pointer: there's only a single address to point at a given Objective-C object, regardless of the static type of the pointer, so covariance/contravariance never requires any thunks, and the block assignment is a simple pointer assignment (+ _Block_copy/_Block_release under ARC).

Comment: Thanks for the great insight and detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

the feature was probably overlooked. There are [commits](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=125445) that show Clang people caring about making covariance and contravariance work in Objective-C++ for Objective-C types but I couldn't find anything for C++ itself. The [language specification for blocks](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html) doesn't mention covariance or contravariance for either C++ or Objective-C.